# Accessing and editing Master page label from child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Basically, I need to validate log-in on a child page which I've successfully done but now I'm required to edit a label on master page to show the Username of the user that successfully log in. This is basically a visual effect problem if you see it just like that but then I'm required to access the master page label from individual child page validate the username there with the table used for log-in and find out the permission status (admin or user), depending on the result activate or deactivate certain command buttons

- My child log-in page is named :- Login.aspx
- Master page :- Site.master
- Master Label:- Label1

Codes I tried to use but they don't quite work

```
Master.FindControl("Label1").Visible=true;
Label lb=(Label)this.master.FindControl("Label1")
lb.visible=true
lb.text=UserName.text
```

Please help, I have been breaking my head for day to no avail got some good answers from here the past which I used hope to have the same luck

Comment: I use "Label Label1 = (Label)Master.FindControl("Label1");" and it works just fine for me.  Check your Label name just to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

If you tell your master page to bind the label's value to `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`, then you dont have to monkey around with anything in the child page.

In fact, I believe there's a built-in asp.net control for displaying the authentication status of a user.. though I could be wrong.